# Heiche Kedusha if enough people won't be answering

Tags: heiche-kedusha

If a shul knows that they will not have 9 people to pay attention to chazarat hashatz and answer amen to the brachot of chazarat hashatz, would it then be better for that shul to do Heiche Kedusha for those services?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17003/759 (though that's probably just be a dupe)

Comment: Shulchan Aruch, from what I recall, is quite emphatic that people respond Amen to chazarat hashat'z. If it's known in advance that this won't happen, what would be the point in doing chazarat hashat'z to begin with?

Comment: Being shorter doesn't make the kedusha or brachos any less of a requirement for a minyan to respond; what would make heche kedusha different from the regular chazara hashatz in terms of "responses" to it?

Comment: If you mean a situation where, say, you have exactly 10 people including chazan, and one or more are in a hurry to leave the shul to get to work, so you'd lose your minyan - that's probably a valid situation.